# How do I make a stroke line and the image behind it transparent in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]I want to be able to have a space between the words and the image. Like a transparent outline. How do I do this?

Comment: Hi. Can you show an example of what you are trying to achieve, or even what you have tried so far, even if it was a failure? We expect a little more effort in questions here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Above there's a sample photo in the bottom layer and the top layer is text. It's simple to get this:

[image]

As you see the empty background checkerboard can be seen between the text and the image.

Select the text. Click the text icon in the Layers panel by holding the Ctrl key to make the selection.

Enlarge the selection few pixels by applying Select > Modify > Expand 5 px (five is used in the example)

Select the photo layer in the Layers panel and press DEL. This makes the selected area permanently transparent.

If you want to use something finer which doesn't delete anything permanently you need something more complicated. It's easiest to keep a spare copy of the photo layer. Only disable it in the layers panel to keep it in safe and invisible.

**I must admit the question is not 100% clear**. You want a transparent zone between the text and the photo. But there must be something in the hole. Such thing as transparent emptiness doesn't exist as a visual possibility. Now there's Photoshop's default checkerboard. I guess you do not want it nor black, white nor any other color.

After deciding your replacement for the transparent emptiness insert it to a new bottom layer.